# How do I install GRUB as a boot loader when I currently use Mac OS X (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub

I currently have a Hackintosh running Mac OS X Yosemite. I'm in the process of updating it to El Capitan any day now. I have an empty drive slot that I'd like to install Ubuntu onto. I'd like to use GRUB as a bootloader for the two OSs, but I'd like the flexibility of swapping out the Linux drive with a drive containing Windows 7 later, maybe.

I know you can install Ubuntu with GRUB at the same time, but I understand that if I do that, I'm sort of committed to Ubuntu, but that if I install GRUB beforehand, my choices aren't so limited.

So, I'd like to install GRUB using my Mac OS X, without using Ubuntu first. I've seen a couple of articles that suggest it's possible, but I'm unclear how much weight I want to afford them.

Is it possible? And if so, could someone explain what to do and/or point me to resources describing how to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could someone answer the question, instead of just editing my wording?